# Qt4 slots and signals: Qt4 has trouble finding the signal

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I am trying to get the statusbar to update with the FPS of the contents of a QGLWidget. I have connected them as follows (In class MainWin):

```
glWidget = new GLWidget;
ui.verticalLayout->addWidget(glWidget);

connect(glWidget,       SIGNAL( updateFPSSignal(float)  ),
        this,           SLOT(   updateFPSSlot(float)    ));
}
```

The slot is as follows:

```
void MainWin::updateFPSSlot(float fps){
this->statusBar()->showMessage(QString::number(fps), 0);
}
```

In the MainWin class definition, I have:

```
public slots:
    void updateFPSSlot(float fps);
```

And the signal is as follows: (From what I understand, this shouldn't be here, but the program refuses to compile without it).

```
void GLWidget::updateFPSSignal(float fps){}
```

I have the following in the GLWidget class definition:

```
signals:
    void updateFPSSignal(float fps);
```

After calculating the fps, I call:

```
emit updateFPSSignal(fps);
```

However, when the app starts up, the following is printed out:

```
Object::connect: No such signal QGLWidget::updateFPSSignal(float) in /Users/usm/Desktop/OGLTest/MainWin.cpp:12
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWinClass')
```

None of the tutorials I've read seem to be any help, and I'm sure the fix is simple for someone more experienced.

Thanks.

Comment: Please write "Qt" and not "QT" for clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you have

```
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget {

   Q_OBJECT

   /* ... rest of declaration ... */

};
```

in your class declaration? and have you put your glwidget.h header into the HEADERS section of your .pro file? the implementation of a signal is done by moc, not you.

Comment: Ah yes, I put Q_OBJECT in the class declaration and I also needed to run qmake before recompiling. Thanks!

Comment: This should also get rid of the need for the braces after the signal declaration, since moc should now be generating an implementation for you.